# JavaScript datetime stamp to SqlDateTime with milliseconds

Tags: c#, datetime, sqldatetime

I have JS datetime stamp being recorded with full millisecond fidelity 1/1000.
(using SQL I understand the precision is 1/300)

I have been using .NET `System.DateTime struct` and I have **not** been seeing the milliseconds being stored in SQL.

```
...   
 [ResponseTimeStamp] DATETIME         NOT NULL,
...
```

with c#

```
//TimeCompleted is epoc 

    DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    qr.ResponseTimeStamp = dtDateTime.AddMilliseconds(item.Responses.TimeCompleted);
```

I am now trying to use `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime` with

```
SqlDateTime dtDateTime = new SqlDateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
qr.ResponseTimeStamp = SqlDateTime.Add(dtDateTime, item.Responses.TimeCompleted);
```

issue is that the method is throwing the exception:

> "message": "The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Add(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime,
>   System.TimeSpan)'

I've tried converting from `epoc` to `TimeSpan`, but the signature requires a TimeSpan which i create but still throws an exception.

```
TimeSpan newSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, item.Responses.TimeCompleted);
```

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Add(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime,
>   System.TimeSpan)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: If you're using SQL Server **2008** or newer, use `DATETIME2(n)` instead - this has an accuracy down to 100ns (if needed) - so it'll handle milliseconds just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to store the time down to the millisecond then you should be using a [datetime2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) or a [datetimeoffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) for your data.

Both these types allow for accuracy down to the millisecond unlike DateTime which only has a resolution of 3 milliseconds.